# PL/SQL - Insert command doesn't execute in EXCEPTION block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this function in PL/SQL where i want to return the salary of a given employee. Also I want to insert values in a table created by me every time the function executes. The problem is that the function inserts the values when it executes without errors, but doesn't inserts when it enters the    `EXCEPTION`    block. I don't get any errors at compile, it just doesn't execute the insert.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(
    v_name employees.last_name%TYPE DEFAULT 'Bell')
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_salary       employees.salary%type;
  v_user         my_info.user%type;
  v_data         my_info.data%type;
  v_command      my_info.command%type := 'f';
  v_no_lines     my_info.no_lines%type;
  v_error        my_info.error%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT USER INTO v_user FROM DUAL;
  SELECT SYSDATE INTO v_data FROM DUAL;
  SELECT SALARY INTO v_salary FROM employees WHERE last_name = v_name;
  v_no_lines := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  INSERT INTO my_info VALUES(v_user, v_data, v_command, v_no_lines, 'No error'); 
  RETURN v_salary;

EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    v_no_lines := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    v_error := 'No employees with given name';
    INSERT INTO my_info VALUES(v_user, v_data, v_command, v_no_lines, v_error); --doesn't make the insert
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'No employees with given name');  
WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN 
    v_no_lines := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    v_error := 'More than one employee with given name';
    INSERT INTO my_info VALUES(v_user, v_data, v_command, v_no_lines, v_error); --doesn't make the insert
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'More than one employee with given name');

WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'Other error!');
END f;
/
```

---

**Later Edit**

I finally managed to make an insert, but only after i execute the function.
I modified the function and deleted all the inserts from it and made it return salary + number of rows affected

```
DECLARE
  v_user         my_info.user%type;
  v_data         my_info.data%type;
  v_command      my_info.command%type := 'f';
  v_no_lines     my_info.no_lines%type;
  v_error        my_info.error%type;
BEGIN 
  SELECT USER INTO v_user FROM DUAL;
  SELECT SYSDATE INTO v_data FROM DUAL;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f('Bad Input', v_no_lines));
  v_error := 'No error';
  INSERT INTO my_info VALUES(v_user, v_data, v_command, v_no_lines, v_error);

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_no_lines := 0;
    v_error := SQLERRM;
    INSERT INTO my_info VALUES(v_user, v_data, v_command, v_no_lines, v_error);
END;
/
```

Comment: which exception block does it go to? Also add     dbms_output.put_line('Error : ' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
    dbms_output.put_line('Error : ' || dbms_utility.format_error_stack); 

to find out which line of code gives you the error

Comment: The first issue I see is that you are trying to insert into the same table in your exception that you are attempting to insert into in your main body block. If the exception occurs on the initial insert, the same exception will occur on your exception block. Are you sure it is not getting into the OTHERS catch?

Comment: Before running an anonymous block, the database marks an implicit savepoint. If the statement fails, the database rolls back to the savepoint. Therefore, if the exception is propagated all the way out all the uncommitted insert statements in your function, including the ones in the exception blocks will be rolled back. You may wish to look at a separate procedure with the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` if you wish to log the details of exceptions.

Comment: @Shankar thanks for the tip, will use that.

Comment: @DrabJay I tried to use it, but couldn't make it work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
DECLARE
  v_user         my_info.user%type;
  v_data         my_info.data%type;
  v_command      my_info.command%type := 'f';
  v_no_lines     my_info.no_lines%type;
  v_error        my_info.error%type;
  v_need_insert  number;
BEGIN
  begin
    v_need_insert := 0;
    SELECT USER INTO v_user FROM DUAL;
    SELECT SYSDATE INTO v_data FROM DUAL;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f('Bad Input', v_no_lines));
    v_error := 'No error';
    INSERT INTO my_info VALUES(v_user, v_data, v_command, v_no_lines, v_error);

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      v_no_lines := 0;
      v_error := SQLERRM;
      v_need_insert := 1;
    END;
  IF v_need_insert = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO my_info VALUES(v_user, v_data, v_command, v_no_lines, v_error);
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COMMIT inside the EXCEPTION block after the insert statement.It would work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).